# Kafka topic with null values

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka streams application which pushes the records to kafka topic (avro serialized). Schema is stored in schema registry.

After the application upgrade ( no change in schema or data), we have started seeing null records in kafka.[ Ofcourse it may be application issue. But the same application worked fine in dev environment ]

The strange thing is that the application while producing the records( & serializing ) is not complaining but when we list the values in kafka topic, a lot of values are null.

```
root@bastion-0:/app/confluent-5.3.0/bin# ./kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server kafka-0.kf-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:9094 --topic topicName --property print.key=true --property key.separator=, --consumer.config /app/client-sasl-ssl.properties --partition 3 --offset 5904
90-5,null
90-8,null
90-8,null
90-8,null
90-9,null
90-9,null
90-9,null
90-9,null
90-9,null
90-9,null
90-9,null
90-9,null
90-9,null
90-9,null
90-10,null
90-11,null
90-11,null
90-11,null
90-12,null
90-13,null
90-13,null
90-13,null
```

What are possible reasons for kafka topic record value to be null ?

Comment: It would be useful if you could show your code that sends said records